# Query fica lenta com ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, order-by

Estou com um problema, tenho uma query e quando eu uso o `ORDER BY` ela fica muito lenta.

> Obs: eu criei um indice para o campo premium e outro para o score

Segue a query completa:

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS id_freelancer,
    p.nome AS nome_freelancer,
    p.score,
    p.titulo_profissional,
    p.dh_premium_expires,
    p.premium,
    p.sobre_mim,
    p.tem_foto,
    p.nickname,
    p.qtde_projetos_concluidos AS qtde_projetos_concluidos,
    p.qtde_recomendacoes AS qtde_recomendacoes, 
    cp_habilidade.id AS id_habilidade,
    cp_habilidade.nome AS nome_habilidade,
    cp_area_de_interesse.id AS id_area_de_interesse,
    cp_sub_categoria.nome AS nome_sub_categoria
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT cp_pessoa.id,
            cp_pessoa.nome,
            cp_pessoa.score,
            cp_freelancer.premium,
            cp_perfil.sobre_mim,
            cp_perfil.tem_foto,
            cp_freelancer.titulo_profissional,
            cp_freelancer.dh_premium_expires,
            cp_usuario.nickname,
            (
                SELECT count(cp_projeto.id) FROM cp_projeto 
                    WHERE cp_projeto.id_freelancer = cp_pessoa.id AND cp_projeto.id_status_projeto = 4
            ) AS qtde_projetos_concluidos,

            (
                SELECT count(cp_feedback_trabalho.id) FROM cp_feedback_trabalho
                    WHERE cp_feedback_trabalho.id_pessoa_que_recebeu = cp_pessoa.id AND cp_feedback_trabalho.recomenda = 1
            ) AS qtde_recomendacoes
        FROM cp_pessoa
            JOIN cp_perfil ON (cp_perfil.id_pessoa = cp_pessoa.id)
            JOIN cp_freelancer ON (cp_freelancer.id = cp_pessoa.id)
            JOIN cp_usuario ON (cp_usuario.id_pessoa = cp_pessoa.id) 
            LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade_freelancer ON (cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_freelancer = cp_pessoa.id)
            LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade ON (cp_habilidade.id = cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_habilidade)
            LEFT JOIN cp_area_de_interesse ON (cp_area_de_interesse.id_freelancer = cp_pessoa.id)
            LEFT JOIN cp_sub_categoria ON (cp_sub_categoria.id = cp_area_de_interesse.id_sub_categoria)
            LEFT JOIN cp_categoria ON (cp_categoria.id = cp_sub_categoria.id_categoria)
        WHERE cp_pessoa.id_tipo_usuario = 2 
            AND CASE WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 100 THEN 1 
                     WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 500 THEN 2 
                     WHEN cp_pessoa.score >= 500 THEN 3 
                END IN (1,2,3)
            AND cp_perfil.tem_foto = 1
            AND (cp_categoria.id = 1
              OR cp_categoria.id = 2
              OR cp_categoria.id = 3
              OR cp_categoria.id = 4
              OR cp_categoria.id = 5)

        ORDER BY cp_freelancer.premium DESC, cp_pessoa.score DESC LIMIT 0, 10
    ) p
    LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade_freelancer ON (cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_freelancer = p.id)
    LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade ON (cp_habilidade.id = cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_habilidade)
    LEFT JOIN cp_area_de_interesse ON (cp_area_de_interesse.id_freelancer = p.id)
    LEFT JOIN cp_sub_categoria ON (cp_sub_categoria.id = cp_area_de_interesse.id_sub_categoria)

    ORDER BY p.premium DESC, p.score DESC
```

Comment: Para otimizar essa query, acredito que você precise de um índice sobre ambas as colunas (um único índice com as duas colunas). Foi isso que você fez?

Comment: Julgo que você está a fazer um `join`entre duas tabelas: p e f. Correto? Mostre o `select` completo

Comment: Na minha opinião, sem olhar as tabelas e consequentemente o restante dessa SQL é quase impossível saber, porque, sua consulta é lenta com **Order By**, tudo vai ser suposição disso e daquilo ...

Comment: Pessoal, atualizei a query. porem dar uma olhada? Muito obrigado. @Fúlvio ramaral bfavaretto

Comment: @user4919 mande as tabelas ??? e outra coisa: Com essa SQL qual o intuito ???

Comment: @Fúlvio de quais tabelas você precisa? Ela é usada para listar usuários (freelancers), a query interna é usada para selecionar os 10 com base nos filtros e a externa é usada para trazer as habilidades e areas de interesse.

Comment: @user4919 todas tabelas envolvidas ...

Comment: Consegui resolver aqui galera, valew mesmo

Answer (score 3):

Crie um índice em ordem **DESC** para as duas colunas ao mesmo tempo e exatamente nesta ordem: `f.premium DESC` e `p.score DESC`

Outra sugestão, por se tratarem de tabelas diferentes é concatenar os dois na consulta e fazer um `Order BY` essa concatenação...

Comment: Rogerio, como seria essa concatenação?